# JavaScript Regular Expression Syntax

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that checks for letters, numbers, and underscores. In .NET, I can do "^\w+$".  However, I am not that familiar with the JavaScript syntax. Can somebody help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't know about it already, you can simply and easily test js on jsfiddle (a handy tool) check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/8WWhV/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious difference is that in JavaScript, you write the regex as `/pattern/flags` -- this is Perl-style. Your "example" would then be `^\w+$` → `/^\w+$/`.

For example, replace multiple `e`'s  with one `e`, case-insensitive search (hence the `i` flag):

```
var s='qweEEerty';
s=s.replace(/e+/i, 'e');
```

Returns: `qwerty`.

Comment: In JavaScript you can also say `new RegEx("^\w+$", "i");` (where the second parameter with the flag(s) is optional).

Answer (score 0):

That same expression will work in JavaScript (there are some differences between .NET regular expressions and JavaScript regular expressions but not in this example).

I recommend that you read [Using Regular Expressions with JavaScript and ActionScript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) to learn a bit more about JavaScript's regular expression implementation.